# Why is there no crown symbol next to the red mickey symbols?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

In Kingdom Hearts Final Mix for PS4, I cleared all the gummi missions for beginner difficulty. I got a bronze crown symbol next to the red mickey symbols for doing so. When I cleared the missions for normal difficulty and also proud difficulty, I didn't get a crown symbol at all. What gives? Is there something else I have to do to get the crown symbol? I would be very grateful if someone could solve this mystery, as it has been really bothering me. That is for beginner mode. I didn't get any crown symbol for normal mode or proud mode, and I have finished all of the missions in both of those modes as well.

[image: Crown emblem in gummi missions]

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot? I'm having a hard time visualizing which crown you're referring too, especially in Kingdom Hearts 1

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for adding that! Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. That's really interesting. I've never seen that crown before, nor can I find any information regarding it